# Replace anything outside the brackets that contained letters only

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**I have here my sample text**

```
[10.5]  : [G  D/F#]
[21.5]  : [D F G] => It's too late
[26.5]  : [D Em A] => It's now done
```

I want to replace(remove) everything outside the brackets that contained the chord names.

I knew how to select inside `/[^\[\]]+([a-zA-Z\#])/g`

**First line selections**

```
G  D/F#
```

**Second line selections**

```
D F G => It's too late
```

**Third line selections**

```
D Em A => It's now done
```

There, I want the output to be (each iteration line by line)

```
G  D/F#
D F G
D Em A
```

How can I invert my regex thus it should inly select the chord names inside `[D F G]` replacing everything outside?

Comment: no, I just wanted to match only the first line whenever that line had been read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with this regex [`\[([A-Za-z\s\d#/]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/sRoc5H/1) to return the values that you are looking for.

**Explanation**

- Match a bracket `\[`
- Start a capturing group `(`
- Match characters in this range one or more times `[A-Za-z\s\d#/]+`
- Close capturing group `)`
- Match closing bracket `\]`

```js
var lines = [
    "[10.5]  : [G  D/F#]",
    "[21.5]  : [D F G] => It's too late",
    "[26.5]  : [D Em A] => It's now done",
    "[26.5]  : [A7/13] => text",
    "[26.5]  : [Asus4] => text",
    "[26.5]  : [Am6] => text"
];
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var pattern = /\[([A-Za-z\s\d#/]+)\]/;
    var result = lines[i].match(pattern)[1];
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: What if more complicated chord names are involved, e.g. A7/13, Asus4, Am6... (numbers should be included, too, i guess;))

Comment: can i do that with regex replace function?

Comment: @Xtravagant In that case you could use [3 capturing groups](https://regex101.com/r/1wyZmp/1). Group 1: All before the match, Group 2: The match. Group 3: All after the match. Then use replace to replace with group 2 only. `for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {console.log(lines[i].replace(/(.*?)\[([A-Za-z\s\d#/]+)\](.*)/, "$2"))}`

Answer (score 3):

split it and second index will have what you want. search for the bracket in that.

```js
  print = console.log;
    strs = `[10.5]  : [G  D/F#]
    [21.5]  : [D F G] => It's too late
    [26.5]  : [D Em A] => It's now done`.split('\n')
    
    for(str in strs){
        str = strs[str]
        str = str.split(':')[1];
        str = str.trim();
        var reg = /\[(.*)\]/i
        print(reg.exec(str)[1])
    }
```

Comment: replace instead of what?

Comment: I mean if I could extract them using replace instead of exec

Comment: no regex object does not have replace function(string does). if you are trying replace everything except that content inside bracket then it is a hard job.

Comment: thank you, this is the alternative, but I've found the first one more convenient to use.